# Wordpress -> Admin -> List All content on a single list (post & custom post type) and set order

Tags: php, wordpress

I need some help with a functionality I want to add to the current site I'm working on. I hope someone can help me.

I want to create a "page" on the admin section to allow the user to order all post, from a couple of content type I created. The admin can reorder that list and then this will show up on a single page (homepage).

I was able to get all post type with [this code](https://github.com/collizo4sky/WP_List_Table-Class-Plugin-Example),  but now, I don't know how to set an custom order.

---

EDIT:
Solved!

**For the list**

I used the code [WP_List_Table-Class-Plugin-Example](https://github.com/collizo4sky/WP_List_Table-Class-Plugin-Example) the update the function get_customers to get the custom types I need (adding a where clause) and remove all bulk functionality.

**For Order**

I used the code founded on the first comment of [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/help-extending-custom-drag-drop-page-ordering-on-admin-page-list-screen) [Original Code](https://gist.github.com/jaredwilli/820633) with several changes to works with different content types [My Code](https://gist.github.com/AgeValed/cfddc04a1e5a12b534c2280b0064b5cd)

Comment: Please edit your question, and add what you tried, and how that failed.

Comment: Well I think I did, I modify the code on the plugin I added on the post, then use the following code http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/help-extending-custom-drag-drop-page-ordering-on-admin-page-list-screen but I changed to works with multiples content type, also added a new column home_order and use that, the menu_order it's used on each content type

Comment: No... Please edit the question, and put the code there... Links die, and this site is about making use of problems for everyone. If you github dies, as Codehaus did, where will your link point to?

Comment: I know, I'll edit the question with all the information

Comment: I edited the question with the solution

Comment: @PabloIgnaciodelaVega add it as an answer and accept it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

**For the list**

I used the code [WP_List_Table-Class-Plugin-Example](https://github.com/collizo4sky/WP_List_Table-Class-Plugin-Example) the update the function get_customers to get the custom types I need (adding a where clause) and remove all bulk functionality.

**For Order**

I used the code founded on the first comment of [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/help-extending-custom-drag-drop-page-ordering-on-admin-page-list-screen) [Original Code](https://gist.github.com/jaredwilli/820633) with several changes to works with different content types [My Code](https://gist.github.com/AgeValed/cfddc04a1e5a12b534c2280b0064b5cd)